# Testing Server Sent Event With Rest Assured Framework

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, rest-assured

I am using spring boot and rest assured to test my REST services

I have a rest controller, such as

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
Flux<String> getFlux() {
...
```

How do I assert on the response body correctly?

I think the value comes back as "data: " for a stream that terminates after one output.

I also have no idea how to test a stream actual works when trying to affect the data asynchronously?

Comment: Do you want to run the test against a deployed app on a remote server or do an integration test?

Comment: Integration/Component test preferably using @SpringBootTest or equivalent

Answer (score 1):

**Reactive Testing**

You should use WebTestClient to test your reactive services.

Here is an example

The service method:

```
public Flux<GithubRepo> listGithubRepositories(String username, String token) {
     return webClient.get()
            .uri("/user/repos")
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Utils
                    .encodeToString((username + ":" + token).getBytes(UTF_8)))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(GithubRepo.class);
}
```

The Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class WebclientDemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

     @Test
    public void test2GetAllGithubRepositories() {
        webTestClient.get().uri("/api/repos")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .expectBodyList(GithubRepo.class);
    }

}
```

Please find the examples here https://www.callicoder.com/spring-5-reactive-webclient-webtestclient-examples/

**Standard MVC Testing**

**MockMVC**

You could use a mock environment where the controller classes are tested without really launching a servlet container:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MockMvcExampleTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("Hello World"));
    }

}
```

**With a running server:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RandomPortTestRestTemplateExampleTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() {
        String body = this.restTemplate.getForObject("/", String.class);
        assertThat(body).isEqualTo("Hello World");
    }

}
```

Please read more about Spring Boot Testing in the official documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing

Comment: I'm not using spring-boot-starter-webflux so that won't work for this case.

Comment: But your signature shows Flux<String> as the return type. What are you using then?

Comment: Just the standard spring-boot-starter-web dependency. Seems to work as there's a mix of Flux and standard returns.

Comment: Ok. I added tests for MVC. It's always best to read the reference manual first.

Comment: As the original post says I am trying to use the rest assured framework as this is more akin to a component/integration test. The response I get back I believe is being received as server sent events as the content looks like "data: <string>". This is what I am trying to assert against.

Comment: By "You should use WebTestClient to test your reactive services." are you saying that Rest Assured does not support event streams?

Comment: @Snackoverflow with WebTestClient you don't need Rest Assured anymore IMHO

Comment: I've given it a lot of hours and I am now completely convinced that rest-assured cannot be used in any (no matter how hackish) way to test the event-stream. You just simply cannot construct a reactive flux stream from an underlying `InputStream` even if you have access to it. So yeah, you are forcibly stuck with `WebTestClient` (which is not bad, it is crazy-simple to use and can even be combined with concurrent rest-assured requests within a single test, no conflicts).